# python treq fails with Twisted/OpenSSL error due to empty trust store on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ssl, twisted

When I run the following sample code on http://www.google.com, it works fine
But when I try on https://www.google.com, I get this error:

```
Requesting https://www.google.com

Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
```

I'm using python 2.7.8, twisted 14.0.2, service_identity 14.0.0, treq 0.2.1, OpenSSL 0.14

```
import treq
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
import sys

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def doit(url):
    print "Requesting "+ url + "\n"
    results = yield treq.get(url)
    print "...got results\n"
    content = yield results.content()
    print "%s"%content
    reactor.stop()

def main():
    url = sys.argv[1]
    reactor.callLater(0, doit, url)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operating system? What distribution of Python? (python.org, system python, homebrew, or conda, for example)

Comment: $ python --version
        Python 2.7.8 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

        $ uname -a
        CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 ST-01-D-007 1.7.33-2(0.280/5/3) 2014-11-13 15:45 i686 Cygwin

Comment: Glyph's workaround works and is critical for Windows Twisted SSL clients. To help others find this, the exact error I got on Twisted 16.3.0 was: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]>]

Comment: I encountered this issue on macOS 10.13 with Python 2, running inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is most likely that you don't have any trust roots selected, so OpenSSL is failing to authenticate the connection.

You can get some trust roots in a format that OpenSSL can consume by doing `pip install certifi`, and then set your `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable to point at the output of `python -m certifi`.  In Python, you can do this with `import certifi; os.environ["SSL_CERT_FILE"] = certifi.where()` at the very top of your script (before you import any OpenSSL bindings).

Comment: Since I didn't say this in my answer, I should point out that we really consider this a bug in Twisted, and what I've posted here is just a workaround.  You should *not* have to do manual configuration just to make outgoing TLS connections.  Specifically, you can follow https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6371